# Hibernate call cast exception

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jdbc, hibernate-criteria

I am having hibernate call to get the data from the table. I am writing the following code :

```
    List<TABLENAME> list = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession().createCriteria(TABLENAME.class).
    add(Restrictions.isNull("column3")).
    add(Restrictions.eq("column4",groupId)).list();
```

But while running I m getting CastException

[image]

Can anyone pls help to do the fix? I dont know why it needs to cast to integer?

Entity Class :

```
public class TABLENAME {

    private Timestamp column3;
    private int column4;
Getter and setters of the above variables.
    

}
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Added. Please check now

Comment: We need to see your entity class.

Comment: Added in the description. Please checl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add(Restrictions.eq("column1",0)).add(Restrictions.eq("Column2",1))
```

Either your "column1" is of type varchar or your "Column2" is of type varchar.

Or

```
add(Restrictions.eq("column4",groupId)
```

**groupId** is not an int...if your column4 is.

Comment: I removed both the restrictions, then also same issue

Comment: add(Restrictions.eq("column4",groupId)). What is groupId? Is it String or Integer? and what is column4 type?

Comment: column 4 is INT(11), Nullable column in DB

Comment: Added the entity  also in the question. Please check that

Comment: is your groupId type int also?

Comment: Oh no I guess, let me check. Thanks